# Передача данных в поля

Tags: javascript, php, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Понадобилось проложить маршрут на яндекс-карте между двумя точками (одна всегда разная). Чтобы еще раз не писать велосипед на яндекс-API я задался вопросом, нельзя ли открыть стандартную страницу (http://maps.yandex.ru/?page=index&rt=&source=tab) и вписать координаты в поля на странице маршрута.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает? Данные то там GET'ом передаются, [вот например](http://maps.yandex.ru/?rtext=55.830042%2C37.439143~55.792149%2C37.873103&sll=37.681445%2C55.788454&sspn=0.645447%2C0.284751&rtm=atm&source=route&ll=37.681445%2C55.788454&spn=0.645447%2C0.284751&z=11&l=map).